# PHPExcel how to get column index from cell

Tags: php, phpexcel

PHPExcel $cell->getColumn() returns 'A', 'B', 'C', ...

which is the best way to get the integer (0, 1, 2, ...) from the cell.

This function doesn't exist.

```
$colIndex = $cell->getColumnIndex();
```

So what is the alternative withoput converting chr to ascii ?

Comment: Keep in mind that getColumn() can return 'AA' (and so on) for columns > 26...

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
$colIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($cell->getColumn());
```

Comment: OK works fine, I notice that the value returned is 1 for column A but $cell = "worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row);
uses 0 for column A
go figure

Comment: Yup, quirky... something I inherited when I took over the development of PHPExcel, but changing it would break backward compatibility for a lot of people

Comment: There is also PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex for those who need to go the other way.

Comment: A great answer can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564155/how-to-get-the-number-of-columns-of-worksheet-as-integer-28-instead-of-excel-l) - helped me a lot -

Comment: @MarkBaker - This question , answers and comments were made a long time ago, but if there arent any solution to this yet? It's a not a big issue but kind of annyoing. You could consider implementing which index to start the column on  and what return value that should be used (e.g. $PHPExcel->setStartColumnIndex(0); $PHPExcel->setReturnValue(string) or $PHPExcel->setReturnValue(int) etc etc). Just a tip! Else this library is AWESOME :-)

Comment: There is a solution.... if you want zero-indexed, then subtract 1 from the returned value.... but it is never a good idea to change a library behaviour to return a zero in this case, when users already have their code written to work with a 1-indexed return, and who will then find their previously working code suddenly broken

Answer (score 5):

You can get column index while iterate.

```
$xls = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($fn);
$xls->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$sheet = $xls->getActiveSheet();

foreach($sheet->getRowIterator() as $row)
{
    foreach($row->getCellIterator() as $key => $cell)
    {
        echo $key; // 0, 1, 2...
        echo $cell->getCalculatedValue(); // Value here
    }
}
```

Comment: And how d i get only the value for the second cell of each row ?

Answer (score 2):

```
If you want to get decrement cell address using this function, you have to use another function with this function as follows.

<?php
echo columnLetter("AB");

function columnLetter($c){


$letter="";
    $c = intval(columnNumber($c));
    if ($c<=0) return '';

    while($c != 0){
       $p = ($c - 1) % 26;
       $c = intval(($c - $p) / 26);
       $letter = chr(65 + $p) . $letter;
    }

    return $letter;

}

function columnNumber($col){

    $col = str_pad($col,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $i = ($col{0} == '0') ? 0 : (ord($col{0}) - 64) * 26;
    $i += ord($col{1}) - 64;

    return $i-1;

}
?>
```