# Count number of columns in sample.xlsx sheet using PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I need to find column count for the table in excel sheet... code in below is my routine for this function...can any one tell me how to count column value in PHPExcel??? this routine counts exact... but it displays result as in alphabets... just like if it has 5 column,its shows E.. how can i display count value in numeric rather than alphabets.... thanks in advance :)

```
$file_name = htmlentities($_POST['file_name']);
$sheet_name = htmlentities($_POST['sheet_name']);
$number_of_columns = htmlentities($_POST['number_of_columns']);
$number_of_rows = htmlentities($_POST['number_of_rows']);

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile("data/" . $file_name);
$objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly(array($sheet_name));
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);

$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("data/" . $file_name);

$highestColumm = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestColumn();
$highestRow = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestRow();

echo 'getHighestColumn() =  [' . $highestColumm . ']<br/>';
echo 'getHighestRow() =  [' . $highestRow . ']<br/>';

echo '<table border="1">';
foreach ($objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getRowIterator() as $row) {
    $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
    $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false);
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
        if (!is_null($cell)) {
            $value = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
            echo '<td>';
            echo $value . '&nbsp;';
            echo '</td>';
        }
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Perhaps this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564155/how-to-get-the-number-of-columns-of-worksheet-as-integer-28-instead-of-excel-l

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert a column name like `'E'` to a column number like `5` using the PHPExcel built-in function:

```
$highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumm);
```