# Convert Excel column coordinates to integer position in PHP

Tags: php, excel, coordinates

I need to convert Excel coordinates (for example "AD45") into X=30 and Y=45 positions in integers.

I have this snippet of PHP code:

```
/**
 * @param  String $coordinates
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getCoordinatesPositions($coordinates) {
    $letters = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z]/', '', $coordinates);
    $numbers = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $coordinates);

    $letters = strtoupper($letters);

    $columnCoordinate = 0;
    $alphabetIterate = 0;

    $alphabetRange = range('A', 'Z');
    $alphabetCount = count($alphabetRange);

    $splittedLetters = str_split($letters);
    $lettersCount = count($splittedLetters);

    $i = 1;

    if ($lettersCount === 1) {
        $columnCoordinate = array_search($splittedLetters[0], $alphabetRange) + 1;

    } else {
        foreach ($splittedLetters as $letter) {
            if ($i !== $lettersCount) {
                $position = (array_search($letter, $alphabetRange) + 1) * $alphabetCount;
            } else {
                $position = (array_search($letter, $alphabetRange) + 1);
            }

            $columnCoordinate += $position;

            $i++;
        }
    }

    return array('column' => $columnCoordinate, 'row' => $numbers);
}
```

My problem is, that this function is not returning correct column value if you pass coordinates with 3 or more letters ("ABC45"). And my colleague said, that this algorithm is also poor performance.

Do you have any ideas for simpler and better performance algorithm? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The @Axel Richter's answer is a good solution and works fine, but it may be improved to:

- Secure against wrong coordinates.
- Reduce code.
- And probably increase performance.

Here is the proposed version:

```
function getCoordinatesPositions($coordinates) {
    if (preg_match('/^([a-z]+)(\d+)$/i', $coordinates, $matches)) {
        $level = strlen($matches[1]);
        $matches[1] = array_reduce(
            str_split(strtoupper($matches[1])),
            function($result, $letter) use (&$level) {
                return $result + (ord($letter) - 64) * pow(26, --$level);
            }
        );
        return array_splice($matches, 1);
    }
    // (returns NULL when wrong $coordinates)
}
```

Using the initial `preg_match()` ensures to avoid working with wrong coordinates, and directly extracts the column part into `$matches['1']`.

Now the main improvement is to use `ord($letter)` to compute the letter's individual value: it avoids creating a temporary array of `range('A', 'Z')`, and simplifies the evaluation.

Then `array_reduce()` allows more compact processing of the column part, which is modified *in situ*, so the final return is also simplified as a simple part of the intermediary `$matches`.

Comment: Simple and few lines of code. Works nicely. I will use this one. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 2):

In principle the algorithm is fine. You can simplify it and make it more general this way:

```
function getCoordinatesPositions($coordinates) {

    $letters = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z]/', '', $coordinates);
    $numbers = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $coordinates);

    $letters = strtoupper($letters);

    $alphabetRange = range('A', 'Z');
    $alphabetCount = count($alphabetRange);

    $splittedLetters = str_split($letters);
    $lettersCount = count($splittedLetters);

    $columnCoordinate = 0;
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($splittedLetters as $letter) {
       $columnCoordinate += (array_search($letter, $alphabetRange) + 1) * pow($alphabetCount,  $lettersCount - $i);
       $i++;
    }

    return array('column' => $columnCoordinate, 'row' => intval($numbers));
}

var_dump(getCoordinatesPositions("ABC456"));
```

For `PHPExcel` see [PHPExcel how to get column index from cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458978/phpexcel-how-to-get-column-index-from-cell).

Answer (score 0):

i have tested both answers with 1.000.000 iterations for finding the row/cell for "XX50" on a MacBook Air M2.

the original code, posted with the question, does it in `2.60` seconds while the accepted answer does it in `2.11` seconds (an `18.84%` improvement).

i needed this for a project where i have to process, in various ways, lots of very large excel files and needed the fastest i can get. so, here is my code which, on my machine, does the test in `1.39` seconds making it `34.16%` faster than the accepted answer.

```
function getCoordinatesPositions($coordinates) {
    
    // continue only if the coordinates are valid
    if (preg_match('/^([a-z]+)(\d+)$/is', strtolower($coordinates), $matches)) {

        // there's nothing faster than having this as static values - ord() is a lot slower
        // even having them start at `1` instead of `0` and not having to do an addition 
        // later on helps
        $lookup = array(
            'a' =>  1, 'b' =>  2, 'c' =>  3, 'd' =>  4, 'e' =>  5, 'f' =>  6, 'g' =>  7,
            'h' =>  8, 'i' =>  9, 'j' => 10, 'k' => 11, 'l' => 12, 'm' => 13, 'n' => 14, 
            'o' => 15, 'p' => 16, 'q' => 17, 'r' => 18, 's' => 19, 't' => 20, 'u' => 21, 
            'v' => 22, 'w' => 23, 'x' => 24, 'y' => 25, 'z' => 26
        );
        
        // no need to `str_split` to get the letters as an array
        // as in PHP $string[$index] works well and it is a lot faster

        $length = strlen($matches[1]);

        $column = 0;

        while ($length--) {

            // this is significantly faster than pow(26, length--) albeit not as pretty
            for ($j = 0, $pow = 1; $j < $length; $j++) $pow *= 26;

            // multiply the value of each letter by its positional weight 
            // (26^(position from the right))
            $column += $lookup[$matches[1][$length]] * $pow;

        }

        return array('column' => $column, 'row' => $matches[2]);

    }

    // if we get this far it means the coordinates were invalid
    return false;

}
```