# PhpSpreadsheets - How get cell coordinate by column and row?

Tags: phpspreadsheet

I want to execute this sum formula, but I am filling the cells with columns and rows, how can I get the name of the last column to place it in the range

```
$sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $score);
$sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(($col + 1), $row, "=SUM(E{$row}:{$col_name}{$row})");
$sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(($col + 1), $row)->getCalculatedValue();
```

I tried

```
$sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, "=SUM(E{$row}:{$sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)})");
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHPExcel how to get column index from cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458978/phpexcel-how-to-get-column-index-from-cell)

Answer (score 2):

Not 100% certain I understand the requirement, but assuming my interpretation is correct, the Cell `getCoordinate()` method should hopefully do what you are looking for. Try this:

```
$sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, "=SUM(E{$row}:{$sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getCoordinate()})");
```